# Extracting page sizes from PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to read a PDF and get a list of its pages and the size of each page.  I don't need to manipulate it in any way, just read it.

Currently trying out pyPdf and it does everything I need except a way to get page sizes.  Understanding that I will probably have to iterate through, as page sizes can vary in a pdf document.  Is there another libray/method I can use?

I tried using PIL, some online recipes even have d=Image(imagefilename) usage, but it NEVER reads any of my PDFs - it reads everything else I throw at it - even some things I didn't know PIL could do.

Any guidance appreciated - I'm on windows 7 64, python25 (because I also do GAE stuff), but I'm happy to do it in Linux or more modern pythiis.

Comment: PIL does not (and most probably never will) support PDFs, because they're a very complex kind of vector graphics. PIL focuses on raster images. Working with PDFs is a task for dedicated libraries, such as pikepdf or pymupdf.

Answer (score 57):

This can be done with [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/):

```
>>> from pypdf import PdfReader
>>> reader = PdfReader('example.pdf')
>>> box = reader.pages[0].mediabox
>>> box
RectangleObject([0, 0, 612, 792])
>>> box.width
Decimal('612')
>>> box.height
Decimal('792')
```

(Formerly known as [pyPdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) / [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/))

Comment: input1 = PdfFileReader(file('example.pdf', 'rb') works for me this way.

Comment: The coordinate values are called points, where by default 1 point is equivalent to 1/72 of an inch. However, each page can define a custom UserUnit, which is a factor that scales all coordinates.

Comment: PyPDF2 also works, to import the library with this line "from PyPDF2 import PdfReader", the rest are the same as above.

Answer (score 23):

Update in 2023-08-30: Provide example pdf, add cropbox

Update in 2021-07-22: original answer was not always correct, so I update my answer.

With [PyMuPDF](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF):

```
>>> import fitz
>>> doc = fitz.open("example.pdf")
>>> page = doc[0]
>>> print(page.rect.width, page.rect.height)
284.0 473.0
>>> print(page.mediabox.width, page.mediabox.height)
595.304 841.89
>>> print(page.cropbox.width, page.cropbox.height)
473.0 284.0
```

Return values of [mediabox](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.mediabox), [cropbox](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.cropbox) and [rect](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.rect) are of type [Rect](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rect.html), which has attributes "width" and "height". For most people, rect is probably the most useful.

These three are identical most of the time, but occasionally they can be very different: cropbox and rect are the visible area of the page (what you see from a regular pdf viewer), while mediabox is the physical medium.

One difference between cropbox and rect is that cropbox is the same as /CropBox in document and does not change if page is rotated. However, rect is affected by rotation. For more information about different boxes in PyMuPDF, you can read [glossary](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html#MediaBox). Also see [PDF documentation](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) 14.11.2.1.

Sample pdf can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-AhweO5evEgLaB668ugyRRcM2_OpAsa/view?usp=drive_link).

Comment: Instead of `doc.loadPage(0)` you can also simply write `doc[0]` :-)

Comment: `page` here has also an attribute `MediaBoxSize` which returns the size.

Comment: This is the fastest wrapper library to read PDF files

Comment: The `CropBox` attribute of `Page` objects returns the *unrotated* size as a `Rect` object. That `Rect` has `width` and `height` attributes. This is a quick way to get to the relevant bits.

Comment: **if page is not rotated** What if the page is rotated? Does the order of width/height change in `MediaBox`?

Comment: @rain01 Order is not changed, but when a page is rotated 90 or 270 degrees, the number of pixels in a column is actually the real width, and the number of pixels in a row is the real height.

Comment: Thank you so much. Presented a great example.

Comment: What unit of measure are width and height? How to get them in centimeters?

Comment: Unfortunately, Pymupdf changes the height of any page to 842 px. until you change the dpi.

Comment: @mmj 1/72 inch, by default. See https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf page 79 UserUnit.

Comment: Looks like "fitz" doesn't work anymore: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend'`, and if I manually install `frontend` from pip, I get another error, so I guess that is not the module it wants

Comment: I've been done wrong by .mediabox and use .rect as my go-to

Answer (score 17):

With [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw):

```
>>> from pdfrw import PdfReader
>>> pdf = PdfReader('example.pdf')
>>> pdf.pages[0].MediaBox
['0', '0', '595.2756', '841.8898']
```

Lengths are given in points (1 pt = 1/72 inch). The format is `[x0, y0, x1, y1]` (thanks, mara004!).

Comment: *"Lengths are given in points"* unless the page contains a **UserUnit** entry which can be used to change the unit here. This option admittedly is used very seldom only.

Comment: I've tried this, but it failed to extract the information sometime, while PyMuPDF (cges30901's answer) performed well all the time. The reason is that pdfrw failed to extract the "/MediaBox" key from the pdf file sometime (wierd).

Comment: "The format is ['0', '0', width, height]"

- This is wrong. The format is [x0, y0, x1, y1]. It does not necessarily need to start with 0.

Answer (score 7):

for pdfminer python 3.x (pdfminer.six) (did not try on python 2.7):

```
parser = PDFParser(open(pdfPath, 'rb'))
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
pageSizesList = []
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
    print(page.mediabox) # <- the media box that is the page size as list of 4 integers x0 y0 x1 y1
    pageSizesList.append(page.mediabox) # <- appending sizes to this list. eventually the pageSizesList will contain list of list corresponding to sizes of each page
```

Comment: works for me too. also do you know the difference between `mediabox` and `cropbox`?

Comment: in short, mediabox is the size of the whole page including the white margins. cropbox is the size of the page + any area used by applications to do any functionality. checkout https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/PDF_Boxes_:_mediabox,_cropbox,_bleedbox,_trimbox,_artbox

Comment: If a cropbox is defined, that's the part of the page a PDF viewer would usually display.

Answer (score 7):

With pikepdf:

```py
import pikepdf

# open the file and select the first page
pdf = pikepdf.Pdf.open("/path/to/file.pdf")
page = pdf.pages[0]

if '/CropBox' in page:
    # use CropBox if defined since that's what the PDF viewer would usually display
    relevant_box = page.CropBox
elif '/MediaBox' in page:
    relevant_box = page.MediaBox
else:
    # fall back to ANSI A (US Letter) if neither CropBox nor MediaBox are defined
    # unlikely, but possible
    relevant_box = [0, 0, 612, 792]

# actually there could also be a viewer preference ViewArea or ViewClip in
# pdf.Root.ViewerPreferences defining which box to use, but most PDF readers 
# disregard this option anyway

# check whether the page defines a UserUnit
userunit = 1
if '/UserUnit' in page:
    userunit = float(page.UserUnit)

# convert the box coordinates to float and multiply with the UserUnit
relevant_box = [float(x)*userunit for x in relevant_box]

# obtain the dimensions of the box
width  = abs(relevant_box[2] - relevant_box[0])
height = abs(relevant_box[3] - relevant_box[1])

rotation = 0
if '/Rotate' in page:
    rotation = page.Rotate

# if the page is rotated clockwise or counter-clockwise, swap width and height
# (pdf rotation modifies the coordinate system, so the box always refers to 
# the non-rotated page)
if (rotation // 90) % 2 != 0:
    width, height = height, width

# now you have width and height in points
# 1 point is equivalent to 1/72in (1in -> 2.54cm)
```

Answer (score 2):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

```
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_002.py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF


def main():

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle)

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # get the width/height
    w = doc.get_page(0).get_page_info().get_width()
    h = doc.get_page(0).get_page_info().get_height()

    # do something with these dimensions
    # TODO

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

We start the code by loading the PDF using `PDF.loads`.
Then we get a `Page` (you could change this code to print the dimensions of each `Page`, rather than just `Page` 0).
From that `Page`, we get `PageInfo`, which contains the width and height.

You can install `borb` by using `pip`:

```
pip install borb
```

You can also download it from source [here](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb).

If you need further examples, check out the [examples repository](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples).

Comment: Can you specify in which unit of measure are width and height expressed in your library?

Comment: Points. By default there are 72 points per inch.

Comment: how does your library handles non-default ppi? Is there a PDFDocument.get_ppi() function?

Comment: There is no such function. But keep in mind `borb` will turn a PDF document into a JSON like datastructure. So if you know where to look (by checking out spec, which can be found in the repository) you can simply do something like `doc['Info']['Props']['ppi']` (keep in mind this is a fictional path).

Answer (score 0):

Using pypdfium2:

```py
import pypdfium2 as pdfium

PAGEINDEX = 0  # the first page
FILEPATH = "/path/to/file.pdf"
pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(FILEPATH)

# option 1
width, height = pdf.get_page_size(PAGEINDEX)

# option 2
page = pdf[PAGEINDEX]
width, height = page.get_size()

# len(pdf) provides the number of pages, so you can iterate through the document
```

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use popplerqt4

```
doc = popplerqt4.Poppler.Document.load('/path/to/my.pdf')
qsizedoc = doc.page(0).pageSize()
h = qsizedoc.height() # given in pt,  1pt = 1/72 in
w = qsizedoc.width()
```

Comment: Poppler [does not currently take UserUnit into account](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1139), so converting the returned values with 1->1/72in may not always return the correct size.

Answer (score -2):

Right code for ***Python 3.9*** and library ***PyPDF2***:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

reader = PdfFileReader('C:\\MyFolder\\111.pdf')
box = reader.pages[0].mediaBox
print(box.getWidth())
print(box.getHeight())
```

For ***all pages***:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

reader = PdfFileReader('C:\\MyFolder\\111.pdf')

i = 0
for p in reader.pages:
    box = p.mediaBox
    print(f"i:{i}   page:{i+1}   Width = {box.getWidth()}   Height = {box.getHeight()}")
    i=i+1
    
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: 2023 update: PyPDF2 was merged back into pypdf. Use pypdf. PyPDF2 is deprecated.