# PDF coordinate system conversion using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I was using a pdf miner to extract data to a xml file, when I noticed that the objects' coordinate system was represented in the following way:

`<textline bbox="187.098,693.242,288.642,709.202">`

How can I convert this coordinates to a pixel system (x,y) using Python and having already parsed the bbox data to a variable in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "pixel system (x,y)"?

Comment: @mkl Sorry for not being explicit, I was referring to a pixel coordinate system based on an x and y axis

Comment: What does "pixel" imply here? Horizontal and vertical units 1/96" wide? Where is the origin of the coordinate system, lower left corner? Are **x** values increasing when going right, **y** values increasing when going up?

Comment: @mkl The origin would be the upper left corner (x increases when going right and y increases when going down). And does 96 represent DPI?

Comment: *"And does 96 represent DPI?"* - If *units are 1/96" wide*, there are 96 units per inch which means 96 DPI.

Comment: @mkl Ok, so if I want the coordinates to be based on 96 DPI, how can I convert the bbox coordinates?

Comment: My comments here were meant to clarify the question. As I am not using python or pdf miner, I cannot give a python answer. In the end you need to get the crop box and the default user space unit size of the PDF page. The latter most often is 1/72", but the former differs more often. I don't know whether these information bits are part of the pdf miner output. If not, you'll have to retrieve them separately from the PDF pages.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the last answer I made my own function because it didn't work. the last answer is correct but fails to correct the y coordinates. therefore you have to get the size of the PDF and substract the pdf coordinates AND THEN Transform it. my function takes three arguments where src is a tuple of 4 float numbers representing (x0, y0, x1, y1). the bounding box co-ordinates, pdf is the object read by the library
pdfrw:

```
    from pdfrw import PdfReader
    pdf = PdfReader(<path>)
```

and im is the PIL object obtained from the image:

```
    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.open(<path>)
```

function

```
    def TranslatePoints(src, pdf, im):

        sx0, sy0, sx1, sy1 = src
        ssx, ssy = (int(pdf.pages[1].MediaBox[2]),int(pdf.pages[1].MediaBox[3]))
        dsx, dsy = im.size
        sy01 = ssy-sy1
        sy11 = ssy-sy0
        x0 = sx0/int(pdf.pages[1].MediaBox[2])*im.size[0]
        x1 = sx1/int(pdf.pages[1].MediaBox[2])*im.size[0]
        y0 = sy01/int(pdf.pages[1].MediaBox[3])*im.size[1]
        y1 = sy11/int(pdf.pages[1].MediaBox[3])*im.size[1]
        return (x0, y0, x1, y1)
```

to check I cropped the image, it works just fine

```
    im.crop(TranslatePoints(src, pdf, im))
```

Answer (score 1):

first let's understand what the numbers generated by pdfminer for bounding box means. bounding box is a list of 4 numbers organized as the following (x0, x1, y0, y1) where x0, y0 are the co-ordinates of the top left point and y0, y1 are the co-ordinates of the bottom right point. basically, we can use those two points to draw a rectangle around the LT object. also a very important info here is that the origin of the pdf page lies in the bottom left not the top left as images (see this: https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/issues/19).
the standard dpi of pdf page is 72 (see this: https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/issues/74) so basically it is in pixel system (this is because the default for png images also is 72 dpi). knowing this information you can implement a function that translates a point or a rectangle points to a new co-ordinate system (produced by supplying a new dpi number) as the following

```
def TranslatePoints(src, srcSize, dstSize):
    sx0, sy0, sx1, sy1 = src
    ssx, ssy = srcSize
    dsx, dsy = dstSize

    dx0 = sx0 / ssx * dsx
    dx1 = sx1 / ssx * dsx
    dy0 = sy0 / ssy * dsy
    dy1 = sy1 / ssy * dsy
    return dx0, dy0, dx1, dy1
```

src: the src rectangle. a tuple of 4 float numbers representing (x0, y0, x1, y1). the bounding box co-ordinates.
srcSize: the size of the pdf page as tuple of two numbers (width, height) which you can get through my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48886525/3022413 (nvm the downvotes it is working and i tested it)
dstSize: the size of the target co-ordinate system. tuple of x and y (max limit of the new co-ordinate system, maybe the size of an image you are trying to plot the rectangles on?)