# Extract page sizes from large PDFs

Tags: python-2.7, pdf

I need to extract the number of pages and their sizes in px/mm/cm/some-unit from PDF files using Python (sadly, 2.7, because it's a legacy project). The problem is that the files can be truly huge (hundreds of MiBs) because they'll contain large images.

I do not care for this content and I really want just a list of page sizes from the file, with as little consumption of RAM as possible.

I found quite a few libraries that can do that (included, but not limited, to the ones in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6230752/1667018)), but none provide any remarks on the memory usage, and I suspect that most of them - if not all - read the whole file in memory before doing anything with it, which doesn't fit my purpose.

Are there any libraries that extract only structure and give me the data that I need without clogging my RAM?

Answer (score 1):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) can do this. It loads the file structure when you open the PDF and only renders each page when you ask for pixels.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import pyvips

i = 0
while True:
    try:
        x = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], dpi=300, page=i)
        print("page =", i)
        print("width =", x.width)
        print("height =", x.height)
    except:
        break

    i += 1
```

libvips 8.7, due in another week or so, adds a new metadata item called `n-pages` you can use to get the length of the document. Until that is released though you need to just keep incrementing the page number until you get an error.

Using [this PDF](https://www.audi.co.uk/content/dam/audi/production/PDF/PriceAndSpecGuides/r8.pdf), when I run the program I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./sizes.py ~/pics/r8.pdf 
page = 0
width = 2480
height = 2480
page = 1
width = 2480
height = 2480
page = 2
width = 4960
height = 4960
...
page = 49
width = 2480
height = 2480
55400:0.19
```

So it opened 50 pages in 0.2s real time, with a total peak memory use of 55mb. That's with py3, but it works fine with py2 as well. The dimensions are in pixels at 300 DPI.

If you set `page` to -1, it'll load all the pages in the document as a single very tall image. All the pages need to be the same size for this though, sadly.

Comment: A very nice solution, working as advertised, but I did have trouble installing `libvips` in a way that could have it recognise PDFs. This led me to a simpler solution that I'll use and post below. Thank you!

Comment: It depends a bit on your platform -- not everyone compiles with poppler support, since it's GPL. libvips can use PDFium as well, but that's /really/ hard to build. Glad you solved your problem.

Comment: We'll see if I can get it to run on Heroku. *Then* my problem will be solved. That's why I went for `poppler` only. But even if that fails, I'll have more libs to try. I really appreciate the help. And the `/usr/bin/time` part was new for me too. I only knew the built in one. Pity that this one's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51559677/1667018), I found that `libvips`, which is suggested there, uses `poppler` (it can fall back to some other library if it cannot find `poppler`).

So, instead of using the superpowerful [`pyvips`](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/), which seems great for multiple types of documents, I went with just `poppler`, which has multiple Python libraries. I picked [`pdflib`](https://pypi.org/project/pdflib/) and came up with this solution:

```
from sys import argv

from pdflib import Document


doc = Document(argv[1])
for num, page in enumerate(doc, start=1):
    print(num, tuple(2.54 * x / 72 for x in page.size))
```

The `2.54 * x / 72` part converts from `px` to `cm`, nothing more.

Speed and memory test on a 264MiB file with one huge image per page:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M\ %e python t2.py big.pdf 
1 (27.99926666666667, 20.997333333333337)
2 (27.99926666666667, 20.997333333333337)
...
56 (27.99926666666667, 20.997333333333337)
21856 0.09
```

Just for the reference, if anyone is looking a pure Python solution, I made a crude one which is available [here](https://github.com/vsego/misc/blob/master/pdf-pages.py). Not thoroughly tested and much, much slower than this (some 30sec for the above).