# Selenium Python get height of PDF using Chromedriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, height

I'm trying to get the scroll height of a pdf file using Chromedriver, Selenium + Python. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/accessibility/products/acrobat/pdfs/acrobat-x-accessibility-checker.pdf")
total_height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );")
```

The output is `925` however, the total scroll height should be more than that as the pdf has 7 pages... thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `925` refers to the height of what is currently visible on the screen, and not the height of the entire document.

Comment: Download the PDF using selenium and get the PDF properties based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230752/extracting-page-sizes-from-pdf-in-python

Comment: @Christine correct, my code is showing the height of the current viewport. But, I want to get the total scroll height of the page, not just viewport height.

Comment: In case there is no way to get the total scroll height, you could always get the viewport height, then scroll down the height of viewport, get the new viewport height, and keep track of a 'sum' until you hit the bottom of the PDF. I am not super familiar with this so this is just a generic suggestion.

Comment: @Christine Scroll down isn't working. It always shows the first page. `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo({0}, {1})".format(x, y))`

Comment: What are you passing in as `x,y`? I would expect something like `0,925` in this case but not entirely sure.

Comment: yes, x is always 0, but, y increases according to viewport. i.e. 925, 2*925 etc.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting 969:

return $('[type="application/pdf"]').scrollHeight

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the total scroll height. It is the height of your viewport.